# How to get the keys in Firestore?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I try get the keys of my collection just the last collection

```
invoices
  -uid
    - invoice
        -uid
          -data
```

How can I access the keys of my collection using Firestore and angularfire2 v5?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok that is the way is work for me

```
 getSnapshot(uid) {
  this.collection = this.fb.collection('invoices').doc(uid).collection('invoice');
  return this.collection.snapshotChanges().map(actions => {
    return actions.map(item => {
      return { id: item.payload.doc.id, ...item.payload.doc.data() }
    });
  });
}
```